# Get Spacy.Vocab.Morphology ids for every Tokens created by spacy parser

Tags: python, nlp, cython, spacy, pos-tagger

The below code is Sample code to get Docs for each sentence.

[Get docs](http://spacy.io/docs/#doc)

To get every word properties, we are using docs and the sample code is below.

[Get Tokens](http://spacy.io/docs/#token)

By digging deeper into the spacy code,I could figure out that for every noun we do have Morphology associated with it.

Check out values of IDs(Dictionary) from this spacy's source code :[click here](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/morphology.pyx)

My Problem:

I am not able to fetch the morphology value for every noun token. how can i get the same..?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain from your choice of words, but it sounds like you're asking how to get the morphological properties for each token. The morphological properties of a token can be looked up like so:

```
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> doc = nlp('Dogs are friendly.')
>>> token = doc[0]  # Dogs
>>> nlp.vocab.morphology.tag_map[token.tag_]
{74: 91, 'Number': 'plur'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason your `nlp.vocab.morphology.tag_map` is `None` I was able to get most of the morphological info through the token themselves:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
for tok in nlp('Dogs are friendly.'):
    print(f"{tok} {tok.morph.to_dict()}")
```